# Using Features to create module with nested field collections

Tags: entities, features

I'm using [Fred Parke's method](http://www.fredparke.com/blog/creating-content-types-and-fields-using-custom-module-drupal-7) to create a content type module by first building the content type and then turning it into a feature and exporting it. It works perfectly well, except for when I include field collections that are nested, one inside another. The exported source code doesn't seem to include those, even when I manually select the field_* types for export.

Is it possible to export nested field collections in a feature? If the answer is *yes*, how can I achieve this?

At this stage, I'm looking at doing it in Wordpress and embedding the result in an iframe, which should tell you how desperate I am.

Comment: Can you be more specific about those "nested field collections" (what "you" mean by that). And include the field names you're using for them? also, are you yes or no reusing the same fields for multiple content types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was running into some limitations in the Features export module (including some obscure bugs) and a misunderstanding of part of the return result for hook_node_info.  All it took was three solid days of debugging and I got it working.  So this one can go away now; given its limited usefulness, I don't mind if an admin wants to just delete the whole question.